# Error while executing SSIS package on specific environment : Connection manager - The specified module could not be found

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I created 4 SSIS packages, two of them are loading text files into a database and work perfectly.
The two others are performing more or less the same actions but are loading Excel files.

It works perfectly in BIDS and on a UAT server (Windows 2003 64 bits).
I know that I have to run the "Excel" packages in 32 bits mode by using the DTExec.exe file located in the 32 version of SQL Server folder, so this is not the issue.

Here is the content of the batch file used to launch the packages :

```
REM Alimentation Commissions ASSURANCE VIE
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTEXEC" /FILE "H:\HUB\DTSX\DWH_IN_ASV_COM_CommissionsAllianzArcalis.dtsx" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING EW
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTEXEC" /FILE "H:\HUB\DTSX\DWH_IN_ASV_COM_CommissionsLaMondiale.dtsx" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING EW
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTEXEC" /FILE "H:\HUB\DTSX\DWH_IN_ASV_COM_CommissionsNatixisLife.dtsx" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING EW
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTEXEC" /FILE "H:\HUB\DTSX\DWH_IN_ASV_COM_CommissionsRejets.dtsx" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING EW
REM FIN IN
```

The problem is that with the same DTSX files and the same BAT file (to start the execution manually) on our PRODUCTION server, the two packages that load Excel files fail with these messages in the log :

```
Info: 2012-02-03 15:52:57.23
   Code: 0x4004300A
   Source: Export du log d'import SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: Validation phase is beginning.
End Info
Error: 2012-02-03 15:52:57.23
   Code: 0x8007007E
   Source: DWH_IN_ASV_COM_CommissionsLaMondiale Connection manager "CNX_SQL_db_AssuranceVie"
   Description: The specified module could not be found.
End Error
Error: 2012-02-03 15:52:57.23
   Code: 0xC020801C
   Source: Export du log d'import Source OLE DB [1]
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "CNX_SQL_db_AssuranceVie" failed with error code 0x8007007E.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
End Error
Error: 2012-02-03 15:52:57.23
   Code: 0xC0047017
   Source: Export du log d'import SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: component "Source OLE DB" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
End Error
```

`Export du log d'import` is the name of the second task :

- First task : extract data from excel, perform some controls, load the data in a table, generate a text file with the rejects, add a line in a log table.
- Second task : export the content of the log table matching the current package ID to a text file.

There is a loop around that, in order to be able to load several files, matching a name template.

`CNX_SQL_db_AssuranceVie` is the name of the SQL Server connection object, used by both tasks, the connection string is built from data in an external XML file.

The DB connection object being a basic SQL Server connection, and the exact same connection string being used by the two other packages that work, I don't understand what is the issue.
And as I don't have a direct access to the PROD server, it is not easy to try things...

So I'm looking for ideas !

Comment: The connection manager `CNX_SQL_db_AssuranceVie` exists in packages that work and do not work. It has the same casing between working and non-working packages? Both working and non-working packages use the same configuration files? Could you post the contents of your batch file for working and non-working so we can see what options are used when invoking the packages (scrub any users or passwords)?

Comment: The configuration is a generic XML file shared by dozens of packages so I don't doubt it is the same. I confirm that `CNX_SQL_db_AssuranceVie` exist (remember : it works on DEV and UAT environments) and is exactly the same on both working and not working packages. The batch is pretty easy and I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Is there any chance the queries used in the OLE DB Reader aren't valid at the moment? Either they reference temporary objects or table/column changes have not been promoted from DEV and UAT into production?

Comment: I checked that. But everything is there (and I have two packages that perform the same queries and work ^^).

Comment: How about the destinations, any chance the source throwing an error is a red herring and it's really the destination object at fault? I've seen scenarios where that has happened. Can you confirm the path to where the Excel files will be created exists and the invoking user has sufficient privileges? If you add `/REPORTING EWI` does anything stand out from the informational messages?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things come to mind. First, I ran into that when my dev/test servers were 32 bit and the production was 64 bit because we were using connection strings in machine.config.  And, of course, there are different ASP.NET directories and therefore machine.config files for 32bit and 64 bit...

Also, I've had problems when running something in production that didn't have enough permissions...  Try opening a command window as Administrator.  Then running your package from that commandline.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by repairing [Microsoft Office Database Engine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734) which I knew I had installed before but it seems that uninstalling Office products might break the Excel-plugin.